# Excel, return text from column A where, column E has the highest value AND column B values equal value in cel G1

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a sheet that list delivery Recipient (col A), delivery Town (col B), and number of pallets delivered to address (col E).

Col G has a unique list of the delivery Towns from col B.

In col K I would like to show the delivery Recipient (col A), where the pallets (col E) is the highest value - but, only where the unique Town in Col G is the same as the Town in Col B.

Is this possible?

Comment: Most things are, can you edit your post to include anything you've tried already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this formula, assuming 100 lines of data (adjust as required)

`=INDEX(A$2:A$100,MATCH(1,(B$2:B$100=G2)*(E$2:E$100=MAX(IF(B$2:B$100=G2,E$2:E$100))),0))`

Confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

The two conditions are that the delivery town matches....and that the max value for that town also matches. `MATCH` finds the correct row and `INDEX` returns the relevant recipient.

If there are two (or more) recipients for that town with an equal max amount it will only return the first one in the list